# how to customize desktops for remote users in windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop

I'm going to use windows server 2012 to install all our accounting softwares required for our company and make a separate and customized desktop for each user in windows server 2012, but from my first attempt all users connected via remote will get a same desktop as administrator and all the server administration tools are also there eventhough not available for them. i would like to know is it possible to make the users profile just like a normal windows 8 and not so much like a server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you log on to a server, you will get a server desktop.

Basically you shouldn't be RDPing to a server, ever, except for administrative purposes.

What you should do is set up Remote Desktop Services and either set up RemoteApp and publish your apps to your users so that they can access them remotely, or build a Virtual Desktop Infrastructure so that your users can RDP to VMs with client operating systems on them, with a personalized load of the apps that only they use on them, etc.

Comment: But do i have to get windows license for each user on my computer? and do i have to buy any extra licenses for windows remote desktop service?

Comment: Yes. Windows includes 2 and only 2 simultaneous interactive connections for administrative purposes. More simultaneous connections would require, e.g., Remote Desktop Services and the purchase of CALs.

Comment: For accounting software server side programs, do you recommend i install them in a virtual machine or in server itself?

Comment: @user3001414 It's usually considered bad practice to install anything on the host machine other than the hypervisor (e.g. the Hyper-V Role.)